# MySQL 5.7 error: Cannot get geometry object from data you send to the GEOMETRY field

Tags: mysql

I have a column that is giving me a headache on MySQL Server 5.7.11.

It was of type `POINT` and I was able to change it to type `GEOMETRY` with no issues.

When I now try and change it from `GEOMETRY` to `POINT` I get the following error:

`Error 1416: Cannot get geometry object from data you send to the GEOMETRY field SQL Statement: ALTER TABLE`table
`CHANGE COLUMN`column_namecolumn_name`POINT NOT NULL;`

I doesn't make sense to me why I could change it one way and not the other.

I have been having trouble with the `POINT` datatype, especially when I try and do select statements, it sometimes comes with the same error.

Answer (score 2):

"GEOMETRY can store geometry values of any type. The other single-value types (POINT, LINESTRING, and POLYGON) restrict their values to a particular geometry type."

So you can convert POINT to GEOMETRY - but because GEOMETRY can contain other geometry values you cannot go the other way.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/spatial-datatypes.html

Comment: What if the data is a valid POINT? The error sounds like it is attempting and failing.

Comment: And I have seen some other cases of this error showing up for certain selects (both before and after the conversion), although I think I will do a separate question for that.

Comment: I don't think it is failing after an attempt to convert a value is made - it is not checking all the values in that column before the update - it is just telling you that the general GEOMETRY column cannot be converted to the specific POINT column.