# C# calling ST_GeomfromText function in INSERT query

Tags: c#, mysql, stored-functions

In C# I'm trying to call that MySQL query:

```
INSERT INTO tbl1 (id, maxLat, minLat, minLon, maxLon, geo)
VALUES (149, 43.20, 43.19, 23.574659, 23.579477, ST_GeomfromText('POLYGON((43.20 23.574659, 43.20 23.579477, 43.19 23.579477, 43.19 23.574659, 43.20 23.574659))'));
```

with that code

```
StringBuilder queryBuilder = new StringBuilder(string.Format(
    "INSERT INTO {0}.geo_log_file (log_file_id, maxLat, minLat, minLon, maxLon, geo)\nVALUES ",
    schema
));

int it = 0;

for (int i = 0; i < rects.Count; i++)
{
    queryBuilder.Append(string.Format("(@log_file_id, @maxLat_{0}, @minLat_{0}, @minLon_{0}, @maxLon_{0}, ?geo_{0})", i));

    if (i < rects.Count - 1)
        queryBuilder.Append(",");
    else
        queryBuilder.Append(";");
}

using (var cmd = conn.CreateCommand())
{
    cmd.CommandText = queryBuilder.ToString();
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@log_file_id", logFileId);

    for (int i = 0; i < rects.Count; i++)
    {
        string geo = String.Format(
                "ST_GeomfromText('POLYGON(({0} {1}, {2} {3}, {4} {5}, {6} {7}, {8} {9}))')",
                rects[i].maxLat,
                rects[i].minLon,

                rects[i].maxLat,
                rects[i].maxLon,

                rects[i].minLat,
                rects[i].maxLon,

                rects[i].minLat,
                rects[i].minLon,

                rects[i].maxLat,
                rects[i].minLon
            );

        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(string.Format("@maxLat_{0}", i), rects[i].maxLat);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(string.Format("@minLat_{0}", i), rects[i].minLat);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(string.Format("@minLon_{0}", i), rects[i].minLon);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(string.Format("@maxLon_{0}", i), rects[i].maxLon);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(string.Format("?geo_{0}", i), geo);
    }

    try
    {
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
    catch (Exception err)
    {
        string q1 = cmd.CommandText;

        for (int i = cmd.Parameters.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
        {
            q1 = q1.Replace(cmd.Parameters[i].ParameterName, cmd.Parameters[i].Value == null ? "NULL" : cmd.Parameters[i].Value.ToString());
        }
        Console.WriteLine(q1);
    }
}
```

And I get that error

> Cannot get geometry object from data you send to the GEOMETRY field

Can anyone help me, I'm out of ideas!!!
I'm sure that the code gives the correct query (in the end I get it in the catch statement). I try it in MySQL Workbench and it works there, but when I call it from C#, bam error.

Comment: What is the Exception type?

Comment: The type of the exception is "MySqlException".

Comment: did you check this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39832575/mysql-5-7-error-cannot-get-geometry-object-from-data-you-send-to-the-geometry-f

Comment: Yep, I told you, the query that C# try's to execute, works in MySQL Workbench

Answer (score 0):

I found what the problem was, I use .NET 4.0 so I think it did not support MySQL's POLYGON variable, when i give the parameters to the MySQL query with 'cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue()'. When I make the hole query as a string, everything is find. I'm not sure for the newer versions of .NET, but with 4.0 you can't add parameters with 'AddWithValue' method if the parameter contain some of the 'ST_GeomfromText' functions.

So, If you had the same problem, just build the hole query as a string and don't use 'cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue()' method.